# min degree at least $n+1/2$, every edge on Hamilton cycle

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Show that in a graph $G$ if $\delta(G)\ge {n+1 \over 2}$ then every edge $e=(u,v)$ is a part of a Hamilton cycle.

Line of thinking: $G'=G/e$ has a Hamilton cycle by Ore's theorem ($d(u)+d(v)\ge n$ for all non-neighbors $u,v$). I would guess I need to somehow adjust the Hamilton cycle and then add back $e$ to it, but I don't see how. If I knew there was a Hamilton path from $u$ to $v$ in $G'$ obviously that would solve it.

Comment: That should be enough. If you extend the hamiltonian cycle in $G'$ to a cycle of $G$ it uses the edge $e$

Comment: Extend how? I don't see how I can break it up and add $e$ to it while still ensuring it is Hamiltonian

Comment: I guess you must visualize this thing. Just to be sure $G/e$ denotes the graph obtained by contracting the edge $e$?

Comment: Oh I was thinking of just removing it. I guess when it is contracted, Ore's condition still holds and that indeed solves the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Use [Hamiltonian Closure](http://www.sfu.ca/~mdevos/notes/graph/445_hamiltonian.pdf). (I tend to use this since this is the only necessary and sufficient condition on Hamiltonian graphs known to me.)

A graph is Hamiltonian iff its closure is Hamiltonian.

Assume we want edge $uv$ in graph $G$ to be in a Hamiltonian cycle. So it suffices to prove that $u\ldots v$ is a Hamiltonian path. Add a new vertex $w$ and join to $u$ and $v$, forming a new graph $G_1$.

$\delta(G) \geq \frac{n+1}{2} $ implies $d(x) + d(y) \geq n+1 $ for vertices $x,y \in G$, hence $V(G)$ induces a clique in closure of $G_1$. After adding all edges in $G$, now since $d(w) + d(x) \geq n+1 $ for vertex $x \in G$, closure of $G_1$ is a clique, which is Hamiltonian. So $G_1$ is Hamiltonian, and there is a Hamiltonian path from $u$ to $v$ in $G$; hence your result.

Comment: We didn't at all study this closure subject, and in fact from the comments to the question I was able to get an answer. This seems to work however...

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat Can you post your solution? I was trying to prove it without the closure, but was unable to do so (hence the delay in posting the answer).